# What are chemical candidates for replicator molecule?

Tags: genetics, evolution, molecular-genetics

I have read `Selfish gene` by Richard Dawkins and idea is that at random some molecule was synthesized that had a property if there is enough 'materials' to construct copy of itself - it would. And then it made bunch of it's copies and then copies started mutating and eventually we got to DNA in us.

In his book he never says what actual molecule is original replicator.

**What are chemical candidates for original replicator molecule?**

Comment: As @AMR said, there are self replicating ribozymes. That's something that we know. There can be several such candidates, theoretically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no accurate answer  , as you say we talk about **candidates** . there is lots of strong theories about the origin of self replicators . **RNA world** was a strong candidate since latest experiments that suggest there is a good chance that some molecules that have simpler structure than RNA , could have a chance to do self replications .
    there is also strong theories such as :

1.Prions that delivered by space objectives and Meteorites .

2.Life's origins may result from low-energy electron reactions in space:

http://phys.org/news/2016-06-life-result-low-energy-electron-reactions.html

---

first self-replicator recreated in lab:

RNA, or something very like it, has long been a strong candidate as the first self-replicating molecule in the origin of life. This is because it can both catalyse chemical reactions and carry genetic information.
But chemists first needed to explain how a large, complex molecule like RNA could form spontaneously to begin the process. They had done so for some, but not all, components of the RNA molecule.

https://www.newscientist.com/article/2088006-building-blocks-of-lifes-first-self-replicator-recreated-in-lab/

The origin of replicators and reproducers:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1664675/

you can also check the topic :The RNA World and the Origins of Life 
from the book :

**Molecular biology of the cell** by Alberts B, Johnson A, Lewis J, et al.

---

after all this article was so innovative for me . I think it's a good explanation for self replication of molecules simpler than RNA.

http://www.nanowerk.com/nanotechnology-news/newsid=40896.php

"Maslov and Tkachenko's model imagines some kind of regular cycle in which conditions change in a predictable fashion—say, the transition between night and day. Imagine a world in which complex polymers break apart during the day, then repair themselves at night. The presence of a template strand means that the polymer reassembles itself precisely as it was the night before. That self-replication process means the polymer can transmit information about itself from one generation to the next. That ability to pass information along is a fundamental property of life"

Comment: The details appeared in a paper titled “Prebiotic Phosphorylation and Concomitant Oligomerization of Deoxynucleosides to form DNA.” The paper’s authors say that their new finding is the latest in a series of recent discoveries pointing to the possibility that DNA and its close chemical cousin RNA arose together as products of similar chemical reactions, and that the first self-replicating molecules—the first life forms on Earth—were mixes of the two.

Comment: https://www.genengnews.com/news/rna-dna-world-circumvents-rna-world-sticking-point/